# Delete All Rows from column range when first two cells are blank

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking for a way to delete all rows if the first two cells in column M (Range specified starting from M6) below a sub total is blank (In this case starting from 392 until 425 has to be deleted). Second Screenshot is expected result.

Previously it works but now it deletes everything and leaves just the top 5 rows of the range.

Take note that for example - Row 1.1 in this screenshot is only 2 rows (merged) consisting of 5 rows each in actual.

My template consists of 3 rows (merged each consisting of 5 rows each) per section and ending with a row called "Sub total". So total of 17 rows per section. Each section when data is entered can consist of 2 rows (merged means 10 rows in total) + 1 row "Sub Total" or 1 or 3 with "Sub Total" in the end of that section. Bottom of the sheet 3 rows are to be kept there (Total, Submitted Invoices total, Difference) and can somehow be used as a reference for the blank rows which are in between.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()

Const Col As String = "M"
Const fRow As Long = 13
Const mcCount As Long = 5

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cCell As Range
Dim r As Long

For r = fRow To lRow - mcCount
    'Debug.Print r
    Set cCell = ws.Cells(r, Col)
    If cCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count = mcCount Then
        If Len(CStr(cCell.Value)) = 0 Then
            cCell.Offset(-1).Resize(lRow - r + 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
        r = r + mcCount - 1
    End If
Next r

MsgBox "Rows deleted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

[image: Before Deletion]

[image: End Result]

Comment: If do add/delete rows in a loop you need to loop from bottom to top (otherwise you change the row counting by adding/deleting rows and Excel jumps rows). Therfore you need to change `For r = fRow To lRow - mcCount` to `For r = lRow - mcCount To fRow Step -1`

Comment: Its deleting from the bottom, but only 5 rows at a time.

Comment: Any suggestions on getting it to reach the first blank cell, below a cell having a value which is > 0 & <> ""

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it is doing.

a) I wouldn't search column M for the last row; use a column that you know will be populated. b) I would start the loop at row 6. c) Your code isn't checking the "first two cells in column M"; I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you're only checking the first cell in M.

I think you'd be far better searching for that integer Item No. as the start of a section and 'Sub Total' as the end of one. You could then check each cell M in that range to see if any data is present. You don't mention whether a '0' counts as empty so you might want to test for that too.

Skeleton code would be a bit like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCheck As Range, rowToCheck As Range
    Dim startRow As Range
    Dim delRanges As Range
    Dim hasValues As Boolean
    
    'Find the data range - note we're starting from row 6.
    'I'm having to use UsedRange as I don't know what your whole sheet looks like.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set rngToCheck = .Range(.Cells(6, "A"), .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Cells.Count))
    End With
    
    For Each rowToCheck In rngToCheck.Rows
        If IsInteger(rowToCheck.Cells(1, "B").Value) Then 'it's the start of a section.
            Set startRow = rowToCheck
        ElseIf Not startRow Is Nothing Then 'we're in a section.
            If rowToCheck.Cells(1, "C") <> "Sub Total" Then 'it's a target data row.
                If Not IsEmpty(rowToCheck.Cells(1, "M").Value) Then
                    hasValues = True
                End If
            Else ' it's the end of a section.
                If Not hasValues Then 'store the section range in the delete range object.
                    Set delRanges = SafeUnion(delRanges, ws.Range(startRow, rowToCheck))
                End If
                'Reset the flags for a new section.
                Set startRow = Nothing
                hasValues = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'Delete the ranges.
    'Note that this is irreversible, so I've put a break point in for your testing.
    If Not delRanges Is Nothing Then
        'Remove this line if you're happy.
        delRanges.Worksheet.Activate: delRanges.Select: Stop
        delRanges.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsInteger(val As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsEmpty(val) Then Exit Function
    If Not IsNumeric(val) Then Exit Function
    If CLng(val) <> val Then Exit Function
    IsInteger = True
    
End Function

Private Function SafeUnion(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set SafeUnion = rng2
    Else
        Set SafeUnion = Application.Union(rng1, rng2)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Actually Column A has nothing at all. Subtotal values are displaying as "-" since its number format is set to Accounting with 2 decimal places and have the formula as =SUM(L161:L175)

Comment: Can something similar to this be a fix ?

Option Explicit

Sub DelBlankRow()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 15), Cells([a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 15))

  rng.Offset(1) = "=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(B2:N2)>0)*(B2:N2<>0))"
  rng.AutoFilter 1, 0
  rng.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
  rng.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Comment: Understood. It's one of the issues with `UsedRange` - if column A is empty then it'll set the range one column off to the right so all the column references will be on column out. I'm using the row count of `UsedRange` to find your bottom row and then ensuring the A column is included in the test range. Feel free to adjust that as you wish.

Comment: I can set a cell with value "X" beyond the set print area as a reference to start the search from the bottom on that cell and upwards till it gets a number > 0 and not equal to "-"

Comment: It won't make any difference to the code. It will still define the same area. I think you may need to edit your question as I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: In Short im looking for a way to delete all rows BElow M34 until M425 as these sections contain nothing. M34 contains the sub total and M426 contains the overall Total of each cell of each section's "Sub Total".

Comment: The code I supplied does that. Just start the loop from the row you want to start with.

Comment: So more like the code has to find the first two cells of column "M" that are Blank in value (though they may contain formulas to obtain values) once that happens then it should start to delete that first blank cell all the way down to a cell that has a value greater than 0 and is not blank or "-" (i.e Row withTotal, which is the Overall total of each section's Sub Total being added there in a single cell)

Comment: Really sorry your code is way too advanced for me :P im trying to understand it

Comment: Start of a section will vary. Standard as per the template is 17 Rows for 1 section. But if an invoice contains only two rows to be entered in a section then that section can contain 12 rows. So its varying.